# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN) Only when running app on device from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm getting a really weird `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN)` crash on my app which is written in swift but only when i run it on a 32 bit device and only if its running from Xcode (the device is still hooked to Xcode), If i start the app without Xcode it runs fine. I can't give any code since no matter what i do i get no stack trace or anything like that .Only the mention error on the AppDelegate, even though the crash is in different screens further in the app (crashes on second screen).

Any idea as to why the crash would happen only when Xcode is running the app

Comment: show your crash log in your question.

Comment: That's the thing..there is no log...i don't get anything when it crashes

Comment: "i don't get anything when it crashes" - not even in the console output?

Comment: Nope not even there (the console output)

Comment: Any luck? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You are using some variable or object which is yet to be initialised. Please review your code and you will get the error. You can add exceptional break point to get the actual position of the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a memory alignment issue. Search on EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN.

https://brewx.qualcomm.com/bws/content/gi/common/appseng/en/knowledgebase/docs/kb95.html

Answer (score 0):

use memcpy

```
 char*Code; int pc;
 double f;

 memcpy(Code+pc, &f, sizeof(f)); // instead of *(double*)(Code+pc)=f; that generates EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN
```